# getimagesize is not working on windows 7 but it is working on xp

Tags: php, windows-7, gd

`getimagesize` is not working on Windows 7 but it is working on XP. When executed first, it returns `FALSE`, when executed again, it returns nothing.

```
function ezImage($image,$pad = 5,$width = 0,$resize = 'full',$just = 'center',$border = ''){
        ...............
        ...............
        ...............
    $imageInfo = @getimagesize($image);

    if (!$imageInfo) {
    //remove tempfile for remote images
    if ($temp == true) unlink($image);
      return false;
    }

          .............
          .............
 }
```

In case of Windows 7, first when it is going inside the `getimagesize` function it is returning 0, and second time this function gets called it is not returning at all. I have checked the URL `$image` and it is fine. If I enter the URL directly in the browser, it displays the image immediately.

First execution throws the following warning message:

`Warning: getimagesize(http://localhost/metornet/metornet_chart_paxalarm.php?title=MetorNet+Statistics&names%5B%5D=03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A48+-%0A03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A49&pax%5B%5D=0&alarms%5B%5D=0&rates%5B%5D=0.0&names%5B%5D=03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A49+-%0A03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A50&pax%5B%5D=0&alarms%5B%5D=0&rates%5B%5D=0.0&names%5B%5D=03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A50+-%0A03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A51&pax%5B%5D=0&alarms%5B%5D=0&rates%5B%5D=0.0&names%5B%5D=03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A51+-%0A03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A52&pax%5B%5D=0&alarms%5B%5D=0&rates%5B%5D=0.0&names%5B%5D=03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A52+-%0A03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A53&pax%5B%5D=0&alarms%5B%5D=0&rates%5B%5D=0.0&names%5B%5D=03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A53+-%0A03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A54&pax%5B%5D=0&alarms%5B%5D=0&rates%5B%5D=0.0&names%5B%5D=03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A54+-%0A03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A55&pax%5B%5D=0&alarms%5B%5D=0&rates%5B%5D=0.0&names%5B%5D=03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A55+-%0A03%2F07%2F12%0A08%3A56&pax%5B%5D=0&am in C:\Program Files\..\..\Includes\ros_pdf_class\class.ezpdf.php on line 1344`

Second execution throws this fatal error:
`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files\.. \..\Includes\ros_pdf_class\class.ezpdf.php on line 1344`

Comment: 'getimagesize()' returns an array. Please share your code how you are calling this?

Comment: PHP is server side - so the OS that you view a PHP page on shouldn't affect it at all; as it's all been processed on the server. Are you sure that your client side code is cross-browser compatible and it's not the difference in browser between the operating systems that is affecting your results?

Comment: I am running my IE browser in compatible mode.Then also it is giving the same issue.

Comment: Do you mean you are running Apache for Windows?

Comment: yes Alvin,I am running Apache on Windows.

Comment: Try to remove the `@` to see any error messages

Comment: I haved removed @ but even that it is not throwing any error.

Comment: @Fergus, But the thing my code is running fine on xp but not running on windows 7, i have chked with even same browser also.same issue is there.i am not able to reach what is the actual issue because of that getimage size is not working.

Comment: @user663995 - I didn't know you meant the server OS. That explains a lot more now! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason in Vista and Windows 7, `localhost/127.0.0.1` doesn’t work out of the box. To get it working you have to add this line to the c`:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file`: `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

Actually you will find this line in the host file, but it is commented, so you can just uncomment the line. `getimage size` is working fine with localhost too. Thank you for your valuable comments and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the second error indicated that you are processing too much information (*Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded*). You can, for debug purposes, alter this in your `php.ini`.

Secondly, there is something wrong with that first error message you posted. (It might be right, but it looks so wrong.) The same part is repeating in it, and it is missing the real error part.

First of all, make sure that the `$image` file you are trying to access exists with [`file_exists()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), and that your current working folder is the right folder with the combination of [`getcwd()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) and [`chdir()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php).

You will also need to check your `phpinfo()` output for the `gd` settings, it might be that you are missing the required library as `gd` functions (like [`getimagesize()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)) are in that certain library.

#### Edit:

I have seen that you mention that `$image` is an URL. Be careful, as it is not a good approach to use remote images in this context. You should always retrieve a **local** copy of the said image file (possibly using [`cURL`](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)) and then parse it locally.

Using the function below ([source](http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/php/php-save-images-using-curl/)), you can create a local copy of the image file:

```
function save_image($img, $fullpath)
{
    $ch = curl_init($img);
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    
    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        unlink($fullpath);
    }

    $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

`$img` is the remote address of the image, `$fullpath` is the local save path.

You can use `ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')` to retrieve the `php.ini` configuration of where file uploads (when you use the HTML form element of file uploading) are saved. On Linux, it's `/tmp`, with [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), it will be `C:\xampp\tmp`.

So, for example, to save a temporary file, you can go `save_image($img, ini_get('upload_tmp_dir')."/".time() );`. It will save a temporary file with the current timestamp, which can easily be deleted afterwards.

Comment: +1, very good advice and a pretty extensive answer that goes beyond the initial scope of the question. I like it! :)

Comment: Thanks Whisperity, thanks for your response,but in my case i cann't check file_exists because file is actually not created initially.we are drawing the image with the url but it is not saved any where.So, i have tested in xp also file_exists with url failing in xp also.In php.ini url setting is on "allow_url_fopen = On".But in xp getimagesize is able to get the size of image but not in win7.

Comment: One new i thing i observed today that when i am passing the system ip address instead of localhost in getimage size. it is able to return the size of image but in when i am giving localhost it is not able to get the size and it is failing.but through web browser i am able to get the image in both the cases means when we use ip address and when we use localhost also.I think the root problem is it not able to access localhost via getimagesize in win7.Is any one give help on this?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Attempt to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: @Whisperity  i have used 127.0.0.1 even it behaves same like localhost.

Comment: I got a solution i want to share with you all,For some reason in Vista and Windows 7 localhost/127.0.0.1 doesn’t work out of the box. To get it working you have to add this line to the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file: 127.0.0.1 locahost ,Actually you will find this line in the host file, but it is commented.Either you have make the line uncommented.Now getimage size is working fine with even localhost also,So thank you for your valuable comments and suggestion.